# How to use Microsoft built in Tests with NHibernate For Repository Layer(DAL)?

Tags: mstest

Can any body tell me how to use Microsoft built in Tests with NHibernate For Repository Layer(DAL)?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I've changed the title of your question; could you give us a bit more information, e.g. what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using NUNIT tests to test NH mappings. 
you create test (regular) that create objects, updates them and delete them.
Just like any other test - you assert for the results by checking the DB after the operation.
(if you delete an object, you should be able to "get" it... ect...)

I create a session in the beginning of each test, and close it at the end.

same goes to any other function the dal has...

[NUnit website](http://www.nunit.org/index.php)